# Correct way to join tables and count

Tags: mysql, join, count

Let's say i have 3 tables.
They are called Users, threads, posts. I need to know how many post & threads 
the user has created in one sql line. What is the best way to do this? The joins i would do something like following, is that correct/the best way to do this? But how do i make the counts?

```
SELECT *,
FROM users
LEFT JOIN threads on threads.user_id=users.user_id
LEFT JOIN posts on posts.user_id=users.user_id
WHERE user_id='1'
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like this which applies and aggregate function to get the total count:

```
SELECT u.user_id, 
    coalesce(TotalThreads, 0) + coalesce(TotalPosts, 0) Total
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN
(
  select user_id, count(thread_id) TotalThreads
  from threads
  group by user_id
) t
  on t.user_id=u.user_id
LEFT JOIN
(
  select user_id, count(post_id) TotalPosts
  from posts
  group by user_id
) p
  on p.user_id=u.user_id
WHERE u.user_id='1'
```

If you want the values separate, then:

```
SELECT u.user_id, 
   coalesce(TotalThreads, 0) TotalThreads, 
   coalesce(TotalPosts, 0) TotalPosts
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN
(
  select user_id, count(thread_id) TotalThreads
  from threads
  group by user_id
) t
  on t.user_id=u.user_id
LEFT JOIN
(
  select user_id, count(post_id) TotalPosts
  from posts
  group by user_id
) p
  on p.user_id=u.user_id
WHERE u.user_id='1'
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have stray comma after `SELECT *`. Second, when you want the threads and posts, why query the user table? Third, why is (is it?) `user_id` a `char`?

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM threads WHERE user_id='1'
SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM posts WHERE user_id='1'
```

Use `UNION` if you want it in one query.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically there. Because `count` is an [aggregate function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx), you can simply group by the `user_id`:

```
select users.user_id as [User ID]
,count(threads.user_id) as [Number of Threads]
,count(posts.user_id) as [Number of Posts]
from users
left join threads on threads.user_id = users.user_id
left join posts on posts.user_id = users.user_id
where user_id = '1'
group by users.user_id
```

This way, your `where` clause becomes optional. You can just remove it if you want a distinct list of all users with their corresponding thread / post count.

Comment: Not needed if you have only one user_id. And you do because of the `WHERE`.

Comment: @BartFriederichs yes, which is why I said the `where` is optional. If there were to be more than one user, just remove it to get them all grouped by user_id (or any other column like username)... or you can target a specific user like they are doing in this instance.

Answer (score -1):

```
    SELECT 
    COUNT() as posts,
    FROM users
    LEFT JOIN threads on threads.user_id=users.user_id
    LEFT JOIN posts on posts.user_id=users.user_id
    WHERE user_id='1'
```

Answer (score -1):

Would this work?

`SELECT COUNT (*) FROM users u, thread t, posts p
WHERE t.user_id=u.user_id
AND p.user_id=u.user_id
AND user_id='1'`

I'm not to hot on SQL...

Comment: true, but an idea can be helpful.

Comment: Use the comment section for that. Or try out your idea, making sure it works and then give the answer.